# Update 100 million rows, minimize impact on concurrent operations

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.5

Wanted to update all rows in  a table of size 1000GB. Tried 2 methods
1)  first tried to update 1 million rows but after this got to know that size increased by 30GB. Since I didn't want to do auto vacuum so I rejected this method.

2) tried to create a clone table and insert all record from current table to clone table. After inserting all data exchanged the table name.  Since I couldn't rename the table name without service downtime so rejected this method also.

Need a way to update all the records without any downtime.

Comment: "*Since I did't want to do auto vacuum*" - why not? That's the only way to reclaim dead speace

Comment: @a_horse_with_no If I update all the rows and do auto vacuum then system performance can go down or even can go for downtime. So to be safer side I don't want to do this. And also I am not sure how long this auto vacuum would take for completion.

Comment: The solution to (auto) vacuum taking too long it to do it **more** frequently, not less (or not at all). Make auto autovacuum **more** aggressive for that table and then just update it. Also: auto vacuum will not cause "a downtime" as it doesn't interfere with other transactions.

Comment: So to make auto vacuum more frequent i would have to change my pg settings which would require restart of pg. Restart is similar to a downtime?

Comment: Just change them for that table using ALTER TABLE. But even changing the auto-vacuum settings globally does not require a restart, you can apply the changes using `pg_reload_conf()`

Comment: See [here](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/autovacuum-tuning-basics/) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/) or [here](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/11/04/autovacuum-not-the-enemy/) for some discussions regarding auto-vacuum. You should also plan an upgrade to the current version (currently 11) as newer versions improve this also

Comment: In my case i have already updated 10M rows without vacuuming so now there are 10M dead tuples. Now if i am going to do an auto vacuum then it is going to affect the other transaction. This case i have checked in lower environment and yes it is affecting other transactions(insert execution time had been increased on that table during auto vacuum).

Comment: There is no way you can do this without any impact at all.

Comment: Tell us more about what you are trying to update exactly. Table definition. `UPDATE` statement. Do you *need* to update all rows at once? Can you "partition" the update in many small updates? How much concurrent write load?

Comment: Basically the update query is like update tableName set a = null, b = null. One more thing is how to avoid active transaction in order to achieve auto vacuum?